# How to convert one date format to another format using angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In my project am getting a date like this **"05/23/2016"** format. But i want to show it in the view like this **"23 May 2016"** using Angular.

How to do it ? Please help...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: I use http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a date object out of your string (in your controller, for example):

```
$scope.dateVar = new Date("05/23/2016");
```

and then use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) in your template:

```
{{ dateVar | date:'dd MMMM yyyy' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the `string` `"05/23/2016"` on `"/"`.

```
$scope.today = "05/23/2016";
$scope.date = $scope.today.split("/");
```

Then convert your `string date` into `Date object`

```
$scope.actualdate = new Date($scope.date[2],$scope.date[0] - 1,$scope.date[1]);
```

Now you can use any combination of the `date filter` from AngularJS docs

```
{{actualdate | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}} // 23 May 2016
{{actualdate | date: 'yyyy dd MMMM'}} // 2016 23 May
{{actualdate | date: 'dd MMMM'}} // 23 May
```

You can use any combination and format the date as you want.

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/mznagsgu/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use angularjs to change the format , use $filter

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

refer to this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Use Angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Before applying filter you date must be in Javascript Date format or in date timestamp.